# Male Platy clamping fins and hiding

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, diseases, freshwater

I got 7 coral red platy for a planted ten gallon tank about two months ago. The water conditions are very good and the temperature is 76. I have 3 males and 4 females, and they have been breeding so I also have 3 three week old fry in there and some that were literally just born so Idon't know how many. One of the male fish had been acting different from the others even since I'd just gotten it. It's been hiding in the bottom and often I can't find it, and its fins are always clamped. It doesn't eat very much either. It is a smaller fish and stays away from the others, who sometimes nip at and chase it. It's seemed to have gotten worse in the past few months and I'm kind of concerned... I read another article where something similar was happening and it said the other fish may also show symptoms too, eventually, but the others are all happy and normal. I buy my fish from American Fish Depot which as far as I know is pretty reputable. Is this just genetics, or is it because of aggression from the other males? Does anyone know what is wrong??
Thanks!

Comment: you say the water quality is good,can you please post the readings PH-Ammonia-nitrite of your tank.

Comment: Not a real answer: fish are like people. They are similar until they are different. Everybody is unique in shape, color and behavior. I have a betta splendes who prefers to spend its time almost at the bottom of the tank instead of floating at the surface.

Comment: Do you have a "hospital" tank you can set up and isolate it from the other fish while you try to  diagnose it? Keeping it separate is good, so it doesn't infect other fish if it's sick, or it will help keep it safe if the other fish are the problem.